# Q: Fix blurry animated line to paths on canvas?

Tags: canvas, d3.js, html5-canvas

When using canvas to make a path animation, It's blurry when moving, when it stops it's clear again. Any idea how to fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/1j1sepa9/3/

```
x = d3.scale.linear();
    x.rangeRound([0, oWidth]);
    x.domain([0, n_columns]);
    // ctx.scale(2,2);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.miterLimit = 5;
    var iTranslate = (ctx.lineWidth % 2) / 2;
    ctx.translate(iTranslate, iTranslate);
    ctx.font = "10px sans-serif";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white"; 

function render() {
    cData.push(Math.abs(90 * Math.random()));
    cData.shift();
        var numberOfItemsToRender = n_columns;
        var startingPoint = 0;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x(startingPoint), y(cData[startingPoint]));
        for (var i = startingPoint + 1, len = n_columns; i < len; i++) {
            ctx.lineTo(x(i),y(cData[i]));
        }
        ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Are you using LCD monitor?

Comment: Macbook pro 2014 retina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a LCD monitor -

This is more related to the monitor and is hard to fix for that reason. One could always buy a high-spec'ed monitor with good response time but I am pretty sure it will be hard to convince users to do the same.

For LCD monitors it is caused by the time it takes to "turn off" a pixel. Also, with bright high-contrast images the time to get to 0 (black) is slightly more visible so you are actually getting a ghost image of the previous frame - of course, not conveniently so that it can appear as motion-blur.

One way to partly get around this is to lower the brightest color as well as increasing the bottom color some.

I added a link to a modified fiddle in the comment section below using altered values. This does of course not fix the problem completely, but adds to the illusion of having an increased response time. My 2 cents.